# How make user or role specific triggers in AZURE DW or Azure synapse?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

Is there any way to make user or role specific triggers in Azure Synapse or azure DW?

Comment: I'm afraid not...

Comment: Azure Synapse dedicated SQL pools does not support DML or DDL triggers at this time.  Azure Synapse pipelines (ADF under the hood) does support event triggers, eg a file landing in a blob.  So if you explained a bit more about what you were trying to achieve overall then someone might be able to help you.  For example, if you routed some activities through a stored procedure which had certain logic built-in, would that have a similar effect?

Comment: @wBob I want to stop certain users or some specific roles from dropping the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a trigger for this. Users can only do what you allow them to do. For example, when you first create a user in the database, they have no permissions. Users can only drop tables if they are members of the database role `db_ddladmin` or they are effectively `db_owner` or sysadmins. So the answer to your question is, make sure that user is not a member of the `db_ddladmin` role in the database.

You can look at using the `DENY` statement for certain roles but I think that would lead to an over-complicated setup that is hard to maintain and administer.  See the [Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation for Synapse for more info.